# How to get timestamp of UIGestureRecognizer event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

My `UIView` (done in `drawRect`) rendering can be slow.  This causes many pinch events to be delivered (up to seconds) too late.  The effect is that my 'drawing' is still zooming in/out after I've long lifted my fingers.

If I had the real timestamp of the pinch events, I could simply ignore them when older than e.g. 1/20 seconds.

Is there any way to get the time?  Or is there another way of getting rid of out-dated gesture events?

Comment: The real fix here is to make the rendering of the view not slow. Can you show the code in drawRect. Fixing that will remove the problem with the gesture recognisers.

Comment: @Fogmeister The `drawRect` calls a single C++ render method that fires of loads of nested draws from multiple modules, I can't show that.  Not drawing details you can't see on screen would indeed help, but that's not the intermediate solution I'm after now having limited time.

Comment: Unfortunately, because drawRect runs on the mainThread your render method will be pausing the mainThread. The OS then queues up the gestures like you said. However, there is no time stamp on the gestures. They are just processed in the order they happen. Your only fix here is to fix the drawRect method. Do you really need to run all the nested renders on each frame? Is there no possible way to use layers (either CALayer or UIView) where you only need to draw the top one etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm working with an existing drawing framework that needs a quick short term fix. Next step will indeed be to avoid drawing/calculations and other techniques.

Comment: When something is blocking the main thread the fix is to stop it blocking the main thread. You can't compensate for that. Unfortunately the only fix here is to fix that optimise that drawRect method.

Comment: Could you possibly show a picture of what it is you're rendering? If it's a drawing framework there's almost certainly a better framework available. It shouldn't be too hard to create on yourself either.

Comment: @Fogmeister I agree, it would be a hack. It's a multiple bar and line graphs (with too many data points in full zoom out) plus a number of annotations on it. I can't show it. It's our own framework and it's not a quick solution to rewrite it.

Comment: It's not so much a hack as it's just not possible to do anything about it.

Comment: There is a WWDC video (from 2013 I believe) that shows how to optimise drawRect in a painting app. Maybe that's worth a watch.

Comment: You should render using CADisplayLink